# Error After Converting Working Python Script to EXE (Python)

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

recently I made a simple game using pygame and it works flawlessly with no errors. Now I would like to convert that to an EXE. I did this using pyinstaller with: `pyinstaller --onefile dodge1.py`

But when I run the EXE I get this error, I do not know what to make of it as I am a beginner and have never seen it before:

```
pygame 1.9.4
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dodge1.py", line 168, in <module>
  File "dodge1.py", line 97, in game_intro
  File "site-packages\pygame\pkgdata.py", line 50, in getResource
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1129, in resource_exists
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1399, in has_resource
  File "site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1452, in _has
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type
[5588] Failed to execute script dodge
```

1

This is what is located on line 168 & 97 as those seem to be the problematic lines:

168: `game_intro()`
97:`LargeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 70)`

Please comment if you want the whole 170 lines of code, I just didn't make this question extremely long.

Comment: will do, give me a couple of seconds. edit: I am sorry but I am unable to get it as text, the cmd window closes in a fraction of a second and i dont have enough time to copy it.

Comment: I added the error to the OP.